# Kentico Client Portal

Tags: kentico

I cannot sign in to Kentico client portal, keep seeing that username and password is not correct, when trying the forgotten password link it prompts me

> no user found

"when trying to sign-up with same email address it prompts me

> email already exist

It seems my account has been disabled ,but how can I enable it back ?

Comment: Hi, please reach out to support@kentico.com with these kind of questions. Mention what account/company you are using and they will surely help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this in the past when I first partnered with Kentico.  Finally after several years I was tired of it and got it worked out by contacting Support at Kentico.com.  They were able to direct me to the person who handles the different portals and was able to clean them up.  Be sure to give them all the email addresses you are using.